# Find $\lambda$ for min. value of $\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^2(x-{\lambda}x)$

Tags: calculus

For the minimum value of integral below, find  $\lambda$.
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^2(x-{\lambda}x)$$

I tried to solve by $\sin^2(x-{\lambda}x) = \frac{1 - \cos2(x-{\lambda}x)}{2}$ but didn't help so much.

Comment: This is a [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2619661/minimization-of-an-integral-depending-on-a-parameter).  Also, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2619712/minimization-of-an-integral).

Comment: Come on, guys. Can it be less than zero? Clearly not. Notice that it is zero at $\lambda=1$.

Comment: How it can't? Isn't the range of trigonometric function [-1, 1]

Comment: It is the integral *of a square*, hence a non-negative number.

Comment: If @help is the same person as shine : it is a very bad habit to ask twice the same question, moreover in a very short time slot. You make people work anew, unaware that indications or answers have already been given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^2(x-{\lambda}x)dx=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1 - \cos2(x-{\lambda}x)}{2}dx\\=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\sin2(1-\lambda)x}{4(1-\lambda)}|_{0}^{\pi}\\=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\sin2\pi(1-\lambda)}{4(1-\lambda)}\qquad ,\qquad \lambda\ne 1$$and for $\lambda=1$ the value of integral is $0$.So we can write the above integral as following:$$I=\frac{\pi}{2}(1-sinc(2-2\lambda))$$ therefore for minimizing the integral first we need to maximize $sinc (2-2\lambda)$ which happens in $\lambda=1$ . So the minimum of the integral happens in this point ant its value is $0$.